# Is equality properly defined on chan?

Tags: clojure, core.async

I want to maintain a collection of channels, with the ability to add and remove channels. Is the equality defined so I can `conj` and `disj` correctly?

In other words, will this **always** work?

```
=> (def chan-collection (atom #{}))
=> (def my-chan-1 (chan))
=> (def my-chan-2 (chan))
=> @chan-collection
#{}
=> (swap! chan-collection conj my-chan-1)
=> @chan-collection
#{#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@6ec3a2f6>}
=> (swap! chan-collection conj my-chan-2)
=> @chan-collection
#{#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@382830a1>
  #<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@6ec3a2f6>}
=> (swap! chan-collection disj my-chan-1)
=> @chan-collection
#{#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@382830a1>}
=> (swap! chan-collection disj my-chan-2)
=> @chan-collection
#{}
```

Comment: Aren't you showing this is working?

Comment: I'm showing that it works today, on my machine. My question is, is it specified to work?

Comment: I'm not sure your edit was entirely necessary, raam86. It's only one sentence with a pretty clear meaning!

Comment: I think it idiot proofs it. I didn't see it before hand.

Comment: I think it is an interesting question. Can you list reasons why it wouldn't work? seems like channals/chan is an abstraction of ManyToMany channel which is essentially a list - https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/d073896192fa55fab992eb4c9ea57b86ec5cf076/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/channels.clj

Comment: I have no reason to assume the equality semantics for `chan`. Collections are compared based on their content, not their reference equality. `chan` isn't a collection, but it's similar. You could argue that two empty `chan`s should be `=` but not `identical?`. Although the example works, there's no reason to assume that it should.

Comment: Your example seems to demonstrate that an empty channel is considered equal to itself, but not to another empty channel. That sounds like expected behavior to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just want confirmation that this is the specification. As an (unrelated) example, `(identical? [] [])` is true on my machine, but that doesn't mean I can extrapolate it to `(identical? [1] [1])`. I just want to know if it's correct to extrapolate one example to general specified behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is true, and changing it would break everything.

Channels are `identical?` if they are the same chan object, and therefore are equal in all cases. All other comparisons of chans are explicitly *not* equal, and this is good for you. You want removal to remove *the exact* chan you ask to be removed rather than some equivalent chan with the same contents. So it's fortunate that **chans that are not identical are also not equal**

```
user> (= (chan) (chan))
false
user> (identical? (chan) (chan))
false
user> (identical? my-chan-1 (chan))
false
user> (identical? my-chan-1 my-chan-1)
true
user> 
user> (= my-chan-1 my-chan-1)
true
```

In the general "Clojure world" this same property is true of all things that are **Identities rather than values**. Identities have values that change over time so it doesn't make sense to say that two [identities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6BsiVyC1kM) are equal if they happen to contain the same value at the moment you ask, even though this may only be true for you and never for anyone else. comparing the values in identities makes much more sense. for example **like chans, atoms with the same values are also not equal** and this is a fundamental property of clojure that will never change.

```
user> (let [a (atom 1)]
        (= a a))
true
user> (= (atom 1) (atom 1))
false
```

Provided you want to remove them by giving the exact chan you want removed as an argument to disj, as you are doing above, rather than some other notion like "remove the channel with 42 in it"

If we do the same setup:

```
user> (require '[clojure.core.async :refer [<! <!! >! chan]])
nil
user> (def chan-collection (atom #{}))
#'user/chan-collection
user> (def my-chan-1 (chan))
#'user/my-chan-1
user> (def my-chan-2 (chan))
#'user/my-chan-2
user> (swap! chan-collection conj my-chan-1 my-chan-2)
 #{#object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x35b61c71 "clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@35b61c71"] #object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x240e86d5 "clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@240e86d5"]}
```

and then ask to have "the empty chan" removed:

```
user> (swap! chan-collection disj (chan))
 #{#object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x35b61c71 "clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@35b61c71"] #object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x240e86d5 "clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@240e86d5"]}
```

we can verify that it does nothing.